# How to get rid of id attributes from EditorFor helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

The standard MVC editor helpers (`@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.whatever)`) all emit id attributes. Because of the way my application is set up, it will be very difficult to make sure these are all unique. I'm not using the id and I don't think MVC or jquery validation needs them either, do they? So it would be best if they were not emitted at all. Is there a way to make that happen?